# Get List of SQL Servers that User has access to

Tags: asp.net, sql

Is there a way to find out a list of the SQL Servers that a windows authenticated ASP.NET user on an intranet site has access to?

I'd like to list them in a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways, to be sure.  One that I'm familiar with is the EnumAvailableSQLServers SMO method (have a look here: http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=45)

The trick is verifying that they actually have access to a given server.  First, you need to define "has access".  Is it whether or not they have a valid SQL login?  Whether or not they can access a certain database or securable?  You'll need to run through the servers returned by SMO in order to validate each one, based upon whatever criteria you define.

Comment: Yeah, you'll either have to attempt a connect as that user and see if it works (time consuming!), or you'll need to log in with a sysadmin account and check some system tables / views to check whether or not that user can connect to that server / any database on that server. Both pretty major undertakings......